# Windows could not start the Apache2 on Local Compute

Tags: apache, xampp

I have tried to change the port 80 to 8000 but unable to start the apache 2.2 i am using xampp server. I have tried many things but unable to solve the issue, Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Any startup errors? Apache will usually let you know why it can't start.

Comment: it says could not start apache 2.2 service on local Computer. Error 3 Sytem cold not fiend path specified

Comment: Check `netstat` and see what's running on your ports. Skype likes to take up port 80 and 443 by default.

Comment: i have checked this and change apache listen port 80 to 8000 because i have found that port 80 used by firefox. i have change this two lines 1. Listen 8000 2. ServerName localhost:8000 in the httpd.conf file

Comment: i dont have IIS server.

Comment: i have also tried with new xampp instalation

Comment: I have found the solution just do the uninstall apache and mysql using  apache_uninstallservice.bat and mysql_uninstallservice.bat and again install xampp which is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution just do the uninstall apache and mysql using apache_uninstallservice.bat and mysql_uninstallservice.bat and again install xampp which is working.